# How to fix GRUB Bootloader (Windows 10 Not Working)

Tags: windows, kali-linux, dual-boot, grub

I recently dual-booted Windows 10 with Kali Linux on my Lenovo laptop. I have installed the GRUB to the master boot record. When it boots up, it shows a Lenovo screen for a few seconds and then shows the Kali GRUB bootloader (Kali dragon background with some OS selections over it). Linux boots fine when selected, but if I choose Windows 10 Boot, it shows a scary black screen similar to CMD that says something similar to this:

```
Windows did not boot correctly. A recent hardware or software change may have caused this. 
1. Get your Windows install and plug it into your computer.
2. Select your language settings.
3. Select "Repair Computer".

If you do not have these anymore, contact your system administrator or computer management.
```

1. I do not have the install because my laptop came with Windows on it.
2. I am the system admin.
3. I do not want to lose all of my files on Windows.
4. I would be okay with removing Linux and possibly re-installing it.
5. I'd like to remove GRUB if possible.

How do I do this?

P.S.: The default bootloader is UEFI, not BIOS.
P.P.S.: If I go to the GRUB command line and type `exit` it will "fix" the drive and boot into Windows.

Comment: 1. I do not have the install because my laptop came with Windows on it. = you are expected to create these from windows menu now, it sucks, it's unfair but that's what it is. You can buy oem disks from your vendor for like £50, or you can buy windows, don't know the current price.
`--------------------------`
3. I do not want to lose all of my files on Windows. = you can mount windows from linux to backup any files, i'd suggest to an external disk if you are going to put a bindows disk in.
`---------------` 4/5 you can try with https://sourceforge.net/projects/refind/

Comment: Yeah, Linux > Windows, but I have a lot of files on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what to do:
If I hold `Fn + F12`, it shows boot options. I selected my hard drive and then performed the Advanced Reboot and changed my UEFI settings to do UEFI Boot by default instead of Legacy BIOS.